# How do I positon a icon on top of an element while using clip-path? The half outside of the element with clip-path applied is getting cutted

Tags: css, css-position, bootstrap-5, clip-path

When I do an clip-path on this element, the part of the telephone icon outside of the element gets cutted.

My code is very simple right now, I am using mostly bootstrap in this project:

```
HTML:
<div class="col-md-3 col-5 rounded-5 bg-white d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <i class="fa-solid icon fa-phone text-yellow-medium position-relative bottom-50 mt-5"></i>
    <p class="fs-4">+351 917 037 172</p>
</div>

CSS:
.contact-card {
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0% 0, 20% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

I'm using the "contact-card" class on the "col-md-3" div.

I removed it from my code just to post the question and to make it clear on where I am stucked.

I'm getting this result at the moment:

[Result that i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr4gj.png)

Here's the result I want to achieve.

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbZCh.png)

This is my first question posted here, so please don't mind any error that might have in my question.

Any help or suggestions will be apreciatted.

Comment: Moving the icon outside of the clipped element would probably be the easiest solution here. The alternative would be to include the icon _inside_ the clip path - you appear to have moved it out of the top of the element here, with a relative position from bottom, so it will be cut even if the clip path leaves the whole top of the card element "uncut".

Comment: @CBroe thank you for the feedback, I will totally try this. I am also trying to resolve this using a div with skew and a ::after to make the border rounded, so I don't have to use the clip-path. But thank you again for your answer :)